# How to run Unit Tests in Angular with dependency on a global

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, internationalization

I'm trying to use a i18n module called lingua in a new angular project (based on ng-boiletplate). You can find this module and a short instruction on [github](https://github.com/ErikAndreas/lingua)

I think it's a great approach bringing gettext style i18n to angular. The integration as mentioned on the github readme did work flawlessly.

But with the integration as it is, based on a manual bootstrap of angular I'm not able to run my tests.

```
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    Lingua.init(document, function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['modulename']);
    });
  });
```

My project is at the moment based on the angular phonecat tutorial. Ang when running the tests I get this error because of the global i18n which should be declared in the "Lingua.init" method before the bootstrap of angular.

```
ReferenceError: i18n is not defined in /path/to/lingua/lingua.js (line 54)
```

Is there a possibility to run that custom bootstrap before the tests get executed? Or is there a way to mock the global?

I'm pretty new to angular, but i realy like the gettext style compared to other i18n modules for angular out there.

I'm in hope someone can give me a hint, because this problem is annoying me for days now ;-(